# Does Scala's string building form ```s"$var1"``` have a name?

Tags: scala

What is the name given to the way that I can create Strings in Scala like this?

```
val foo = "hello"
val bar = "world"

val s = s"$foo $bar"   /// <-- Does this construct have a name?
```

I'm trying to find if Javascript has a similar way of building strings and I wasn't sure what to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

ES6 has ['template strings'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), if you're using ES5 you're out of luck. Coffeescript has string interpolation that compiles to regular string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that underscore.js has a nice [templating function](http://underscorejs.org/#template), though it's not exactly string interpolation.